# software to detect face in javascript

Tags: javascript, camera

I am triying to do a little software to make a selfie and I need something that with a canvas, detect your face and then make the photo.

Can you recommend me something good?

Regards,

Roth.

Comment: Maybe take a look at posts such as [this](https://itnext.io/face-api-js-javascript-api-for-face-recognition-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-bcc2a6c4cf07)? First thing that I found on Google... PS. You may also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tensorflow.js for that https://js.tensorflow.org/demos/ that would be an option for someone familiar with machine learning / computer vision.

Another solution is to have a script in Python running and sending data to and from a web client using websockets like done in this project: https://github.com/ragulin/face-recognition-server

No matter the approach the FPS you will get will be rather low, the workflow for it would look something like that:

1. Capture webcam frame from the canvas.
2. Freeze the webcam capture for a second or two.
3. Send that frame to the backend.
4. Return JSON data whether there is a face or not.
5. JSON data is red by a JavaScript function and then it captures the webcam canvas.